# Collection Days from Accounts Receivable Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an AR table with

```
Client ID: Client number
InvoiceNumber: Number of invoice
ARtype: 1=Invoice, 4=Payment and few more variables. I am only interested in mentioned ones.
Posting Date: Date time of transaction.
```

I want to run a query to show me days it takes to collect the payment from the time of issuing invoice from the table. I have use following query but cannot get my head around using condition in datediff function.

```
Select InvoiceNumber, datediff(d,Min(postingdate),Max(postingdate)) as Days

from AR

group by InvoiceNumber


Adjustment: sample data
arcltid  ARCltNum     ARType      ARDate        ARAmt      ARApplyto
8144        DDC         1       08/31/2016 0:00  5900       115908
8144        DDC         1       05/31/2016 0:00    0        114014
8145        DDC         1        04/30/2016 0:00    0       113584
8144        DDC         1       04/30/2016 0:00   1600      113583
8144        DDC         1       04/04/2016 0:00    0        110163
8144        DDC         1       02/29/2016 0:00   2200      109790
8144        DDC         4       09/27/2016 0:00   -1950     110163
8144        DDC         4       10/17/2016 0:00   -2500     114014
8144        DDC         4       10/17/2016 0:00   -2800      115908
```

I am only focusing on 1 and 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CASE for this:

```
select
    InvoiceNumber,
    datediff(
        d,
        min(case when ARType = 1 then postingDate end),
        max(case when ARType = 4 then postingDate end)
    ) days
from AR
group by InvoiceNumber;
```

Comment: This is giving me a lot of null values. Any idea, why?

Comment: Possibly because you don't have either artype = 1 or 4 or both for those invoice numbers

Comment: @Invisible Please post some sample data in the question for us to test our solutions

Comment: i have posted sample data but it is not showing up in good format.

Answer (score 0):

You want something closer to this:

```
SELECT invoice.InvoiceNumber, datediff(d, invoice.postingDate, payment.postingDate) as Days
  FROM (SELECT * FROM AR WHERE ARtype = 1) invoice
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM AR WHERE ARtype = 4) payment
         ON invoice.ClientID = payment.ClientID
        AND invoice.invoiceNumber = payment.invoiceNumber
```

Comment: I am only getting nulls. Any idea why?

Comment: Nulls just for the Days column? Some sample data would help us untangle this.

Comment: I have edited the question with sample data. Any suggestions? Thank you.